# Config ckeditor pasteFilter for disallowed patterns

Tags: ckeditor

How do I use `pasteFilter` to strip every attribute of a table/tr/td? Is there a way to set the black list patterns like the way `config.disallowedContent` does?

Answer (score 0):

So I read the [code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/5b0bded0cb114c4c4a4d5dc95af41e894e859da6/plugins/clipboard/plugin.js) and come up with the following hack:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (evt) {
var pasteFilter = new CKEDITOR.filter();
    pasteFilter.allow({
        $1: {
            elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
            attributes: true,
            styles: false,
            classes: false
        }
    });
    pasteFilter.disallow("...");
    evt.editor.pasteFilter = pasteFilter;
});
```

Funny how I usually find my own answers quickly only after posting my questions to stackoverflow.

Comment: will this work with ACF enabled? I tried but it didnt work even with simple config.pastefilter doesn't do anything